# Using MySQL to Create a Login page in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, authentication

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I can connect to my MySQL datababse no problem by clicking my login button.

Now I can't figure out how to query the database and check if username and password are correct, and switch to a different form, to display the data loaded from the database.

Can Anyone Help?? Please

I should have posted my Code

This is Login.vb Form

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Login
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection

    Private Sub Login_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login_btn.Click
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=johnny;database=test"

        Try
            conn.Open()
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                connectionstatus.Text = "Connected to Database"
                conn.Close()
            End If
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            connectionstatus.Text = "Unable to Connect to Database"
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

When the login is completed, and username and password are correct, I want it to load Main.vb.

Comment: This is trickier than it seems. It's _easy_ to build something that seems to work, but is horribly insecure, such that you'll quickly find yourself hacked or leaking passwords. Save authentication code for the pros: people who work with _security_, and not just general development, day in and day out.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following article, it explains how to create the login form using mysql and vb
http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3

Comment: This is what I used. This just forms the connection. It isnt actually pulling any data from the database. This just connects to it. It doesn't query a table for username and password, It refers to the database's username and password.

Comment: you can try this it explains how to execute some query on database using vb http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-4

Comment: Eh. This isn't helping me much. I have a simple form, username box, and password box, and a login button. On login, it connects to the database just fine. But I want it to check the username and password, and if correct, open a different Form, and pull that row from the database and display it on the next Form.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a sql command that will find a record in the database table that match the username and password values. So something like

```
SELECT username, pwd FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @username and pwd = @pwd
```

You will need to pass the username and password as parameters... **do not pass the textbox values directly as you will be open to Sql injection**. Execute the command if you get a row then the user exists and their password was correct. **You should encrypt the password and only store the encrypted password in the database...**

Look for tutorials on how to query database once you connect to it.

Comment: Don't store the password at all...store a one way hash of the password instead

Answer (score -2):

you should never post your mysql information inside of any program - instead try having it connect via php - that way your mysql information is secure